# Windows Backup fails to create Shadow Copy

Tags: windows-7, windows-7-backup

Windows Backup is failing with:

> A shadow copy could not be created.
>   Please check "VSS" and "SPP"
>   application event logs for more
>   information.   Details: The writer
>   experienced a non-transient error.  If
>   the backup process is retried, the
>   error is likely to reoccur.

The VSS event log says:

> Volume Shadow Copy Service error:
>   Unexpected error calling routine
>   IVssAsrWriterBackup::GetVolumeComponents.
>   hr = 0x80073bc3, The requested system
>   device cannot be found. .
>
> Operation:    OnIdentify event
>   Gathering Writer Data
>
> Context:    Execution Context: ASR
>   Writer    Writer Class Id:
>   {be000cbe-11fe-4426-9c58-531aa6355fc4}
>   Writer Name: ASR Writer    Writer
>   Instance ID:
>   {108b2193-aab4-4e86-a66a-5232a580ee7e}

The SPP log says:

> Shadow copy creation failed because of
>   error reported by ASR Writer.  More
>   info: The requested system device
>   cannot be found. (0x80073BC3).

System is 64-bit Windows 7.  I'm trying to back up one internal drive to another (C->E). C: is a 111GB partition on a 160 GB Intel SSD (The System Reserved partition is 100MB). E: is a 2TB Hitachi hard drive (one partition, NTFS formatted).

**Update**:

Perusing the links provided by echarnley gave me the idea to try marking the C: partition active (it wasn't).  That let me backup an image of C: without error, but if I selected any locations for files to backup, it failed with:

> The system cannot find the file
>   specified. (0x80070002)

Marking the system reserved partition active instead solved that problem, full backups (image + files) now complete without error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like Windows backup is having a problem with your system reserved partition - try these steps: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968128.

Also, there is a discussion of the error here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/smallbusinessserver/thread/627e1b48-3478-4fae-a7a2-d1703dd131d9/

Comment: How do you mark a partition active? Disk Manager?

Comment: Could someone point me to an article explaining which should be marked as active: System reserved partition or C:? I would've thought the answer would be always the same but seem to be getting mixed messages.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error happen on Windows 10.  It was due to an old Acronis lower filter.  I used their cleanup tool (https://kb.acronis.com/aticleanup)

This error is the same one I had:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-backup-fails-after-installing-feature/af4893c4-b660-4305-a6c2-1e84b376af5e

> Volume Shadow Copy Service error: Unexpected error calling routine
> IVssAsrWriterBackup::GetDiskComponents.  hr = 0x80042302, A Volume
> Shadow Copy Service component encountered an unexpected error.
>
> Check the Application event log for more information.
>
> .
>
> Operation:
>
> OnIdentify event
>
> Gathering Writer Data