# Windows Backup failure creating system image

Tags: windows-10, uefi, gpt, windows-backup, volume-shadow-copy

On a UEFI W10 computer Windows Backup fails to create a system image, there's some VSS (Volume Shadow Service) errors logged with detail "the requested system device could not be found".

I can't understand what device it's taking about.

Here's the system log export:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B4qnFjiSSB9OkPObfj1tmUFVuIlDJDbp/view?usp=drivesdk

Maybe it fails to access the system reserved EFI partition, there's some solutions for this just for MBR disks, not for GPT.

Any suggestions?

Regards

Comment: Please open the event log again. Find the event you're talking about, right-click it and copy event details as text; then paste them to your question. Please use the curly brackets around the text to keep the formatting readable.

Comment: This just popped up on my system: [https://superuser.com/questions/262876/windows-backup-fails-to-create-shadow-copy](https://superuser.com/questions/262876/windows-backup-fails-to-create-shadow-copy) - does it help you?

Answer (score 1):

Realistically, you are wasting your time.

Windows Backup is deprecated. Microsoft has stopped its development
and is recommending using third party software for backups.

We are seeing on this site an increasing number of errors with
Windows Backup both in creating the backup and (much more worryingly)
with restoring the data. Several posts on our site bear testimony.
Microsoft has removed the option to use this alongside their file history,
because of errors caused when scheduling both.

I suggest following Microsoft's recommendation and using a
third-party product. My favorite is
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html),
but there are other
[alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/aomei-data-backuper/).